# Unity freezes when I apply a LINQ method to a SortedDictionary. What could it be?

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a game in Unity and I recently changed a List I had in my code for a SortedDictionary<Datetime, SomeClass>. But when I apply the LINQ methods Last() or ElementAt() Unity just freezes and doesn't even send an error message. It just freezes. In my code there is no **while** loop, so an infinite loop is not the case. There are only one simple **for** loops and some if statements.

Here is the problematic code and I marked the lines with possible errors:

```
public SortedDictionary<DateTime, Quote> PricePattern(Stock s, int days, float trend)
{
    SortedDictionary<DateTime, Quote> quotes = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, Quote>();

    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        Quote q = new Quote();
        float a = Calculations.SampleGaussian(0f, 0.01f);

        q.openPrice = 0;
        q.minPrice = 0;
        q.maxPrice = 0;
        q.volume = 0;

        if (i == 0) {
            q.closePrice = Mathf.Round(100 * s.currentPrice * (1 + trend + a)) / 100;
        } else {
            q.closePrice = Mathf.Round(100 * quotes.Last().Value.closePrice * (1 + trend + a)) / 100; //PROBLEM HERE
        }

        if (days == 1) {
            q.date = TimeController.currDay;
        } else if (i == 0) {
            q.date = s.ipoDay;
        } else if (i > 0){
            q.date = quotes.Last().Key.AddDays(1).CheckIfWeekDay(); //PROBLEM HERE
        }

        quotes.Add(q.date, q);
    }

    if (days > 1) {
        List<DateTime> datesToRemove = new List<DateTime>();
        for (int i = quotes.Count - 1; i > quotes.Count - 15; i--) {
            if (quotes.ElementAt(i).Key >= TimeController.currDay) { //PROBLEM HERE
                datesToRemove.Add(quotes.ElementAt(i).Key); //PROBLEM HERE
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        foreach (DateTime item in datesToRemove) {
            quotes.Remove(item);
        }
        datesToRemove.Clear();
    }

    return quotes;
}
```

Does anyone know what could it be? I'm stuck in it for two days.

Comment: Before anyone asks, the CheckIfWeekDay method just checks if the day is a weekday. If not, it assigns the next weekday to the variable.

Comment: You could try to decompose the faulty line and use a breakpoint. You would then be able to pinpoint whether it goes with Last or AddDays or CheckIfDays.

Comment: ``ElementAt`` and ``Last`` will both throw an exception if your quotes dictionary is empty. Not sure if that's what is causing your problem, but you might want to check it.

Comment: The last two methods are used in other parts of the game and it works fine. When I press play, a main menu of my game appears and it works fine. When I press to create new game, unity freezes. And after some hours I realized it was because this part of the code. If I remove Last() and ElementAt from the method, it works fine. But I need them to access the SortedDictionary :(. But thanks for the comment <3

Comment: Hey @defaultUsernameN, the thing is that Unity doesn't even send error messages to the console. It just freezes. I've never seen this happening before and I'm pretty sure it was supposed to work. I'm using Unity 2021.1.1f btw

Comment: @LucasFerreira It could be your second for loop and the quotes.Count - 15. Unless you know that the container is always above 15. You can access a sorted dictionary by index, but if this count drops below 0 it will not be in the bounds of the dictionary anymore. I am not sure if Unity handles this exception gracefully or just crashes.

Comment: Also, `Add` will throw if you attempt to insert a duplicate keys.

Comment: @user3657449, I tried commenting this block of code but the game crashes anyway :( The Count is supposed to be at least 200, but I'll make this block of code prettier one day hahaha

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, I checked now to see if this was the problem and it's not :(. But thanks <3

Comment: I'm starting to think this is some kind of bug with the unity version. But I really doubt that :(

Comment: Use **Stopwatch** class and output some dump data(send to console or Debug.WriteLine), maybe the **Calculations.SampleGaussian** is taking too long,. Also you can create 2 variables: one for the result of **TimeController.currDay** and second for the **quotes.ElementAt(i).Key**, and again use the Stopwatch

Comment: In general for many items you always have to iterate the entire thing in order to get the last item ... why not simply store the last assigned date in a variable and use it directly?!

Comment: If you encapsulate the whole method with a try and catch, do you get an exception, or is Unity swallowing the error?

Comment: @AndersBjerin and others: Usually if there is an exception Unity would log the exception and not execute the code further. If this is executed onna background thread it might swallow the the exception and not log it .. still it wouldn't execute the code any further .. so this wouldn't freeze/crash Unity usually ... A freeze is usually either a never ending loop or just something that takes very long to execute

Comment: True, and when it happens I would start adding some Debug.Log() or dump data as @Igor suggests.

Comment: Just to give an update, I tried Stopwatch and it still freezes. A never-ending loop is not the case here, because this code worked when I was using a list, so the only thing that changed was that I added those LINQ methods. I'll keep investigating here and If I have any more updates I'll post here. Thank you all for helping guys <3

Comment: I found out what the problem was. As my SortedDictionary was supposed to hold over 2000 items sometimes, the Add() method was taking a long time, so to overcome this I was keeping the items in a list and them at the end I converted it to a Sorted Dictionary. So I guess it was my bad for not using Igor answer properly. @Igor, please create an answer so I can accept your suggestion and thank you so much for all the help <3

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave my last comment as an answer (but won't accept it because I'm waiting for @Igor to post his answer), so it can be of help to someone else.

I was making several mistakes, so I'll leave here some advice that I learned while trying to fix my code:

1. If you need to create a List or Dictionary with a large size, create it with a predefined capacity. It will save a lot of time and your collection won't need to resize every time.
2. If you need to use a SortedDictionary and fill it with a huge amount at the start, first create a Dictionary and then convert it to a SortedDictionary.

**How to set capacity to a List or Dictionary**

```
int capacity = 500;

List<T> exampleList = new List<T>(capacity);

Dictionary<TKey, TValue> exampleDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity);
```

**Convert Dictionary to SortedDictionary**

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue> exampleDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> exampleSortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(exampleDictionary);
```